# Total number of order as per current month and product added by logged user on product list page using woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to display total number of order in product list page. I can get simple count but not get with below conditions.

1) Display on product list page

2) Product added by logged in user not all user

3) Order of current month (not product)

I have tried below code.I have added this hook to my theme function file.

```
$table_posts = $wpdb->prefix . "posts";
$table_postmeta = $wpdb->prefix . "postmeta";
$table_items = $wpdb->prefix . "woocommerce_order_items";
$table_itemmeta = $wpdb->prefix . "woocommerce_order_itemmeta";

$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$current_month = date('m');
$current_year = date('Y');
$orders_ids = $wpdb->get_results("
            SELECT $table_itemmeta.meta_value as product_id
            FROM $table_itemmeta, $table_items, $table_posts
            WHERE  $table_items.order_item_id = $table_itemmeta.order_item_id
            AND $table_items.order_id = $table_posts.ID
            AND $table_posts.post_status IN ( $orders_statuses )
            AND $table_posts.post_author = ".$user_id."
            AND year($table_posts.post_date) = ".$current_year."
            AND month($table_posts.post_date) = ".$current_month."
            AND $table_itemmeta.meta_key LIKE '_product_id'
            ORDER BY $table_items.order_item_id DESC"
        );
```

Below id the place where i want to display.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try something like this for display your order total :

```
<?php echo $order->get_total(); ?>
```

I hope it's works for you !

Best regards.

Comment: I want to add this on product list page so i don't get $order there.

Comment: you mean here woocommerce/templates/order/order-details.php

Comment: Please check my screenshot where i want to display.